# Angular2 Provide

Tags: angular, provider

I upgrade my project to Angular RC to Final today and i have a problem to convert =>

```
provide(Http, {
   useFactory: (xhrBackend: XHRBackend, requestOptions: RequestOptions, accountEventService: AccountEventsService) => {
       return new HmacHttpClient(xhrBackend, requestOptions, accountEventService);
   },
   deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, AccountEventsService],
   multi: false
}
```

I try to use the same code with final version, but i don't found some solution.

Thank's for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax has change to object literal like:

```
{provide: Http, 
   useFactory: (xhrBackend: XHRBackend, requestOptions: RequestOptions, accountEventService: AccountEventsService) => {
       return new HmacHttpClient(xhrBackend, requestOptions, accountEventService);
   },
   deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, AccountEventsService],
   multi: false
}
```

Comment: Thank's for your help